# None of my bash commands work so i can't install apache ant

Tags: apache, bash, ant, path, osx-yosemite

Im trying to install apache ant but a lot of my bash commands don't work.
i entered

```
echo $PATH
```

and got a really long path back

```
/Users/arthurlecalvez/.rbenv/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin::/usr/local/bin:/Users/arthurlecalvez/adt/sdk/tools:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home:/usr/local/bin:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin::/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home:/Users/arthurlecalvez/ant/bin
```

How do i fix this

Comment: You should have `/usr/bin:/bin` in your `PATH`.

Comment: It's not like it's the end of the world, but you have a ton of repetition there...

Answer (score 1):

Run
`PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH"`
Apparently most of the directories in your `$PATH` are either in a `Library` dir or `/Users/arthurlecalvez`, neither of which has the bash commands by default. Apparently *some* commands work because `$PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin`, but most won't.